# RangeError: Invalid typed array length: when running Angular on https in local PC

Tags: angular, https, buffer

I'm trying to add https for my local Angular Web app development.

When I use `ng serve` command, everything works fine. I created and installed a local SSL certificate on my mac.

After that I'm trying to run my Angular app using the comnmand `ng serve --ssl true`. The app compiles without any error. When I hit any url, the app crashes and I'm getting the below error. What could be causing the error?

```
internal/buffer.js:788
class FastBuffer extends Uint8Array {}
RangeError: Invalid typed array length: -4095
```

Answer (score 6):

Looks like the problem was with the node version. I downgraded my node version from 11.x to 10.x and it's working now.

Comment: this should be the accepted answer for now. I don't know what in NodeJS > 10.x.x is causing this to break for some "older" versions of angular apps, but this was my issue as well. Just downgraded with `nvm` to nodejs version 10 and it all just worked.  fwiw I'm using Angular 6.x.x